# Change the ActionMailer SMTP settings on action mailer rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to change my ActionMailer SMTP settings on a ActionMailer class, however I'm not able to change it, this is what I've tried.

```
class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def sample
    deliver_with(:mailgun)
  end

  def deliver_with(server = :transactional)
     Rails.application.config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = Rails.application.secrets[:smtp][server]
     ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = Rails.application.secrets[:smtp][server]
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how is done:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'mailer'

  after_action :config_smtp

  def sample
    deliver_with(:mailgun)
  end

   private

   def config_smtp 
      mail.delivery_method.settings.merge! @smtp_settings if @smtp_settings
    end

    def deliver_with(server = :transactional)
      server = server.to_s
      unless Rails.application.secrets[:smtp].keys.include? server
        server = "mandrill"
      end

      @smtp_settings = Rails.application.secrets[:smtp][server]
    end
```

And on your secrets:

```
  smtp:
    mandrill:
      :address: 'smtp.mandrillapp.com'
      :port: 587
      :user_name: '123'
      :password: ''
      :authentication: 'plain'
      :enable_starttls_auto: true

    mailgun:
      :address: 'smtp.mailgun.org'
      :port: 587
      :user_name: '123@em.123.com'
      :password: ''
      :authentication: 'plain'
      :enable_starttls_auto: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to change those settings in the environment files (development.rb, production.rb, test.rb) and not within the class definition.

Comment: I need to change within the class definition because i will use multiple smtp servers/